# Null Pointer Exception in working with AutocompleteTextView and BaseAdapter

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, autocomplete, baseadapter

I have an `AutocompleteTextView` and I wrote the below adapter for that. I want to get data from Web API and this works correctly and I can to get data from the server. The below code shows the below error when I write a text on `autocompleteTextView`. I debug my code, this error shows after call `notifyDataSetChanged` and call `getViewMethod`. I don't know what is my problem.

Another thing, I get a list of objects from the server (I mean like name,family,id) and I want to show just one part of that (I mean, I want to show name) and for this, I create a Custom adapter.

My Adapter:

```
public class DropDownAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private static final int MAX_RESULTS = 10;
private Context mContext;
private List<TestModel> resultList = new ArrayList<TestModel>();
private boolean placeResults = false;
private Object lockTwo = new Object();
private Object lock = new Object();


public DropDownAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return resultList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return resultList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = view;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_row_dropdown, viewGroup, false);
    }
    TextView textView = v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    textView.setText(resultList.get(position).code);
    return view;
}


@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            final FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    filterResults.values = new ArrayList<String>();
                    filterResults.count = 0;
                }
            } else {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("token", OfflineData.getGUID(mContext));
                    jsonObject.put("code", constraint.toString());
                    jsonObject.put("state", false);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Type type = new TypeToken<ServiceResult<List<TestModel>>>() {
                }.getType();
                WebService getBranchCodeListWebService = new WebService(AppConstant.URL_LISTINGDATA, "TestMethod", type);
                getBranchCodeListWebService.addOnCompletedCallBack(new WebService.OnCompletedCallBack() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletedCallBack(boolean isSucceed, Object returnedObject) {
                        if (isSucceed) {
                            if (returnedObject != null) {
                                ServiceResult<List<TestModel>> response = (ServiceResult<List<TestModel>>) returnedObject;
                                if (response.IsSuccess) {
                                    if (response.Result.size() > 0) {
                                        resultList.clear();
                                        resultList = response.Result;
                                        filterResults.values = resultList;
                                        filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        placeResults = true;
                        synchronized (lockTwo) {
                            lockTwo.notifyAll();
                        }
                    }
                });
                getBranchCodeListWebService.execute(jsonObject);

                while (!placeResults) {
                    synchronized (lockTwo) {
                        try {
                            lockTwo.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
```

Error Result:

> ```
> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getImportantForAccessibility()' on a null object reference
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getImportantForAccessibility()' on a null object reference
>     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2382)
>     at android.widget.DropDownListView.obtainView(DropDownListView.java:305)
>     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1408)
>     at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1257)
>     at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:613)
>     at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1217)
>     at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1086)
>     at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1068)
>     at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:285)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
> ```

Create adapter in MainActivity:

> ```
>  autoCompleteTextView = findViewById(R.id.branchCodeEdittextAutocomplete);
>     autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(2);
> ```

```
    DropDownAdapter dropDownAdapter=new DropDownAdapter(this);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(dropDownAdapter);

    autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //go to next page... or anything like this
        }
    });
```

Comment: Which `TextView` does throw the error? The `textView` in `DrowDownAdapter.getView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the correct view,Change your `return view` to `return v`

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = view;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_row_dropdown, viewGroup, false);
    }
    TextView textView = v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    textView.setText(resultList.get(position).code);
    return v;
}
```

and you don't have  to assign view every time you can use `view` it will hold the reference of your view in the adapter, so you can remove the line `View v = view;` and replace your code as

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_row_dropdown, viewGroup, false);
    }
    TextView textView = v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    textView.setText(resultList.get(position).code);
    return view;
}
```

Hope this helps...